# Change text color of WebView URL to white

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to change the color of the WebView URL to white when offline, hide with padding or whatever it is so that the URL is not visible when the application is offline.

[image: screenshot]

```java
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webView.loadUrl("https://google.com-example");
swipe.setRefreshing(false);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home-offline/home-offline.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please apply below code in your home-offline.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><HEAD><meta user-scalable=yes" /></HEAD>
<body>
<div style="color: #FFF;">
#replace content with your offline html content#
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the blank page inside WebView Client to your WebView and display toast to a user that "You are offline please Turn On Internet".

```
webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
```